# Needed help to make multiple Checkbox inline in Cakephp 2

Tags: css, checkbox, cakephp-2.0

Update................. Solved it.
I want to make my multiple Checkbox inline in Cakephp 2. I use `display: inline` but no luck.

Here is my code -

in App controller-

```
public $guest = array('1'=>'Yes','2'=>'No');
    public function beforeFilter() {

        $this->set ('guest', $this->guest);

    }
```

In ctp i write this -

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 form-group" >

    <?php
         echo $this->Form->input('Guest', array('style' => 'float: left; display: inline','type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $guest));
    ?>

</div>
```

Can I get help?

Solved program-

```
 <?php
                           echo $this->Form->input('Guest',array('type' =>'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox','options' => $guest, 'class'=>'checkbox-inline
                            '));

                         ?>
```

Here is my output, but I want it in one row:

[image]

Comment: Could you include the outputted HTML in your question?

Comment: @ovokuro  edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as you didn't respond to my previous edit of this answer, I've decided to dig into the issue once again :)

By carefully examining code provided I may guess that you are using Bootstrap, in Bootstrap you should use form-check-inline class for the inline checkboxes positioning. In your code you can achieve it this way:

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <?php
       echo $this->Form->input('Guest', array('class' => 'form-check-input','type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $guest));
      ?>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is official documentation:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline

Comment: sorry for that, i was out of network for two days. but yeah i solved it. just take a class in from handler and call checkbox-inline. it's works
<php
 echo $this->Form->input('Guest',array('type' =>'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox','options' => $guest, 'class'=>'checkbox-inline
                            '));
?>